# How to configure eclipse formatter to run only when there are no compile errors

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I have a very annoying problem with Eclipse.

I've configured the formatter and use save action to have formatted code with every save.

The problem is the formatter itself. Nearly every time when I save with a compile error the formatter removes lines (sometimes more then 100 lines) of my code. This problem is reproducable when starting the formatter manually.

And a 'compile error' is not only missing braces, even a missing semicolon causes text blocks to fly away.

I use Eclipse Mars but I think this problem already was in Eclipse Indigo. I'm not 100% sure but I think before Indigo the formatter only started when there were no compile errors to avoid such problems.

How can I get this behaviour back that formatter only runs with zero compile errors?

Comment: Only a suggestion, when type CTRL+S to save and eclipse formatted your code. Type only one time CTRL+Z, your code will have saved and format will have reversed. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I already do this but it is still frustrating. Sometimes I do not even realize it when I close a file and save it for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Eclipse Mars with the similar auto-format-on-Save settings. However, do not face such issues. Its correctly formatting the code, deleting none even in case of compilation errors.

Comment: Probably it has something to do with a awkward format configuration ?!